# Get a Future[List[Future[T]]] but need Future[List[T]] (enrichment patttern)

Tags: scala

Link to live code on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jenwirth/xLXVELTJRASmIFQ1d8jAiw)

I'm making a http request which returns me a `Future[List[Post]]`. Each of these posts contains an id (`someId`) which i need to resolve with a second service. This service returns a `Future[String]`. I'll use this resolved value together with the original `Post` to construct a `Result` object.

I am inside a akka http server and making requests to these other back-end services. So i want to return a `Future[List[Result]]`, but so far i keep getting stuck with a `Future[List[Future[Result]]]` (with code that does not feel very clean either)

```scala
case class Post(t: String, someId: Int)
case class Result(t: String, resolved: String)

def resolveId(id: Int) : Future[String] = Future(s"$id")

val f = Future(List(Post("a",1),Post("b",1), Post("c",2)))
val result: Future[List[Future[Result]]] = for {
    l <- f
} yield for {
    e <- l
} yield for {
    r <- resolveId(e.someId)
} yield Result(e.t, r)

//val neededResult : Future[List[Result]] =
```

I have been trying without for comprehensions and playing with `flatMap` every here and there, but can't get those to compile. It also feels this is a very common scenario, but have been searches today without any results. In essence:

- get a future of n objects
- make n calls to a 2nd service
- return a future of n objects using combined values (enrichment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `Future.sequence`**

The `Future.sequence` method takes a `List[Future[T]]` and converts it into a `Future[List[T]]`:

```
val f = Future(List(Post("a",1),Post("b",1), Post("c",2)))

val neededResult : Future[List[Result]] = 
  for {
    l    <- f
    tupL <- Future sequence (l map (post => resolveId(post.someId).map(s => post.t -> s)))
  } yield {
    tupL map Result.apply.tupled
  }
```

Or, in descriptive form:

```
val neededResult = 
  f.flatMap(l => Future sequence (l map (post => resolveId(post.someId).map(s => post.t -> s))))
   .map(_ map Result.apply.tupled)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are interested in functional programming and Cats you can also use traverse (or sequence).

```
import cats.implicits._

case class Post(t: String, someId: Int)
case class Result(t: String, resolved: String)

val f: Future[List[Future[Post]]] = Future(List(Future(Post("a", 1)), Future(Post("b", 1)), Future(Post("c", 2))))

val result: Future[List[Post]] = f.flatMap(_.traverse(identity))
```

Traverse is basically the same than Future.sequence + map but it will work with any Applicative (not only with future). Then you have a Future[Future[List[Post]] and with flatMap you remove one future.